# Traveling in Schengen before and after expiry of Swedish residence permit

Tags: schengen, sweden, permits

I entered the Schengen area on my visa free (Canadian) passport and stayed for two months in Schengen countries, and applied for a temporary residence permit in Sweden to extend my total stay in Sweden for another 3 months after the expiry of the visa-free 3 months. The extension was granted, but it was written in the corresponding letter that I must leave Sweden on or before the expiry of my permit.

Now, as far as I understand, my Schengen visa-free period should renew upon the expiry of the Swedish three-month extension. Is this correct? Does this mean that I can travel in Schengen for 3 months again on my Canadian passport or not, once the Swedish permit expires?

Also, with this temporary residence permit, can I travel to Finland or other Schengen countries (that is, before my Canadian passport Schengen period renews)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The counting of days for the purpose the 90/180 calculation does not include the days during which your temporary residence permit is valid.  Article 6(2) of the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02016R0399-20190611):

> 2. For the purposes of implementing paragraph 1, the date of entry shall be considered as the first day of stay on the territory of the Member States and the date of exit shall be considered as the last day of stay on the territory of the Member States. Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States.

If the duration of your temporary residence permit is 90 days or more, then you will indeed have 90 days available after it expires.  However, individual countries differ on the question of whether it's necessary to leave and reenter the Schengen area in these circumstances.

> with this temporary residence permit, can I travel to Finland or other Schengen countries (that is, before my Canadian passport Schengen period renews)?

Someone with a residence permit from a Schengen country is allowed to visit the rest of the Schengen area *subject to the 90/180 rule.*  If you have exhausted your 90 days because you were in the Schengen area during the 90 days preceding the start date of your residence permit, then you cannot travel to other Schengen countries.  If you were present for fewer than 90 days then you have a few days available to travel to other Schengen countries.

Comment: I was in the Schengen area for two months when I applied for the extension, but the extension counts from the following day of the day on which my visa-free stay expired.